# How to insert data in database of custom checkout step fields in magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, checkout, database, magento2.4.6

I have created an new checkout step that has one input field.
I want the value of that field to be stored in a database.

Comment: Create a API endpoint, post that data and save it.

Comment: thanks;
How will it be visible in admin panel??

Comment: When you have data in db, you can display anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can take inspiration from this module. https://github.com/sbodak/magento2-checkout-custom-form

Also this article can be followed.
https://www.magetrend.com/blog/magento-2-add-custom-checkout-field/